# Looking for a recommended SVN link

Tags: svn, gnome, opensuse

I am looking for a recommended link to download a Tortoise equivalent for OpenSUSE with GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a few in the past, and not found anything as good as TortoiseSVN. But that was a while ago--probably 3 years ago. More recently, I've just used the command-line.

But when I originally looked, I eventually settled on [RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/). Not as good as TortoiseSVN but not too bad. There's also PySVN Workbench, part of the [PySVN project](http://pysvn.tigris.org/). These don't integrate nicely with the Gnome file manager, however, like TortoiseSVN does with Explorer.

A while ago, I also looked at [NautilusSVN](http://code.google.com/p/nautilussvn/), which looked promising albeit immature. Now that has turned into [RabitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), and it aims to support multiple VCS including Subversion.

Comment: It looks like RapidSVN is what I'm settling on for now. Thanks for the comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct port of Tortoise, but I imagine you're just looking for a SVN GUI Client. Here is a great extension for Nautilus to give it SVN capability.

http://naughtysvn.tigris.org/

Comment: That looks like a dead project. Is it alive?

Comment: If a new project scares you how about this client: http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html